# Blazor Server simple onchange event does not compile

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

So I want to do a plain and simple onchange event. When the user changes an option in a dropdown that is not part of any form, I want it to change my Store class (which is a stand-in for what you would do with React-Context).

So I have my component here:

```
<select @onchange="OnRestaurantChanged">
    @foreach (var restaurant in _restaurantStore.State.RestaurantList)
    {
        <option value="@restaurant.Id">@restaurant.Name</option>
    }
</select >
```

and my separate component code file here:

```
using MenuApp.Stores.Restaurant;

namespace MenuApp.Pages.Components.Restaurants
{
    public partial class RestaurantSelector : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        private IRestaurantStore _restaurantStore { get; set; }

        public string RestaurantId { get; set; }

        private void OnRestaurantChanged(ChangeEventArgs event)
        {
            _restaurantStore.ChangeSelectedRestaurant();
        }
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do, I get the following compiler errors, despite the fact that every single tutorial or example seems to work without these errors.

[image: Compiler errors]

If I remove the event parameter from the function then everything seems to compile. But I need the id of the restaurant that the app is changing to, so having a blind function run on change is pointless to me.

I was thinking of binding to a variable and then using the onChange to send the bound variable to my store function, but I think that double binding is not only unnecessary but might cause other problems.

How can I access the ChangeEventArgs?

Comment: NOT use "event" as variable, is a reserved word, use, e.g. `e` :`private void OnRestaurantChanged(ChangeEventArgs e){console.WriteLine(e.Value)}`

Comment: Javascript habits, hadn't used the keyword before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// private void OnRestaurantChanged(ChangeEventArgs event)
   private void OnRestaurantChanged(ChangeEventArgs @event)
```

`event` is a reserved word. You can 'escape' that with a `@`. General C# rules, nothing to do with Razor.

Comment: Javascript habits. Also I hadn't used the keyword before. Thanks.